# Get node ID of added data/row

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

This cannot be that hard. I've found nothing in documentation.

Using a basic table with rows. I'm adding data into the table as part of paste facility, the objects are all unique.

I was using addItems, adding data as an object i.e. addItems(object), this then gets added as a node, but how do I get the id of that added node.

addItems returns void so unless you set your own RowNodeId you can't get the node after the add as far as i can tell.

**UPDATE:**
Use the RowNodeTransation object returned from updateRowData

Comment: Would you mind to create a small trivial example of your scenario somewhere like StackBlitz?

Comment: Thanks for enquiring, i've updated my answer, I'm not sure if that RowNodeTransation would have given me what i'm after but setting my own row node made more sense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

did you try `gridOptions.api.applyTransaction`

here is a code snippet which gives you node which gets added/deleted/updated using above method.

```
    function addItems() {
    var newItems = [createNewRowData(), createNewRowData(), createNewRowData()];
    var res = gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({ add: newItems });
    printResult(res);
    }

    function printResult(res) {
      console.log('---------------------------------------');
    if (res.add) {
        res.add.forEach(function(rowNode) {
          console.log('Added Row Node', rowNode);
        });
      }
      if (res.remove) {
        res.remove.forEach(function(rowNode) {
          console.log('Removed Row Node', rowNode);
        });
      }
      if (res.update) {
        res.update.forEach(function(rowNode) {
          console.log('Updated Row Node', rowNode);
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggesion, but the updateRowData does itself return RowNodeTransation object as i mentioned in my question, so in that sense they are identical. I also do not have the applyTransaction available on GridApi object i am using v22.1.2